# Listview in Popup menu doesn't work properly

Tags: android, listview, popup, onitemclicklistener

> I have a listview in popup menu, it appears correctly but onitemclicklistener doesn't work for that listview.

```
public String[] pop={"a","b","c","d"};
```

> My adapter

```
final ArrayAdapter<String> popadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
              android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, pop);


public void onClick(View v) {
            popUpView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.popup,
                    null); // inflating popup layout




            mpopup = new PopupWindow(popUpView, 250, 140);
            mpopup.setAnimationStyle(android.R.style.Animation_Dialog);
            mpopup.showAtLocation(popUpView, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            mpopup.setTouchable(true);
            mpopup.setFocusable(true);
            mpopup.setOutsideTouchable(true);
            mpopup.setContentView(popUpView);
            ListView lv=(ListView)popUpView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            lv.setAdapter(popadapter);
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {
                    mpopup.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

            });
```

> I can't find the solution

Answer (score 0):

Create your own adapter class extending BaseAdapter. There you will find **getView()** method. Implement onClick method there, it will work.

Don't use this,

```
final ArrayAdapter<String> popadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
              android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, pop);
```